# why jquery is not loading in wordpress page?

Tags: customization, theme-development, jquery

I want to add jquery plugin to wordpress webpage to provide some animations.
I have downloaded "jquery.plate.js" from jqueryscript.net and saved it locally in my custom themes,(js/jquery.plate.js) js folder.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="jquery.plate.js"></script>
```

- I have added the above code in my header using "echo get_template_directory_uri();" function.

not working!

- tried with adding following code in function.php:

  ```
  function my_extrajs() { ?>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo 
    get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.plate.js"></script>
    <?php }

  add_action('wp_head', 'my_extrajs');
  ```

Still not working!

- Tried with adding another code in functions.php:

  ```
  function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.plate.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.plate.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );}
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
  ```

not working!!

```
    $('.text-white.follow').plate();
```

this code is i used to retrieve jquery animation.for the following element:

```
      <div class="col-md-1 col-2 social">
                        <span class="text-white follow"><label>FOLLOW</label></span>
                        <span><a href=""><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/social1.png"></a></span>
                        <span><a href=""><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/social2.png"></a></span>
                        <span><a href=""><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/social3.png"></a></span>
                    </div>
```

Any idea, where i missed??

Also,i am beginner in wordpress.Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score -1):

I think , you did mistake here

`wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.plate.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.plate.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );`

try below line

`wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-plate-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.plate.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );`

Comment: still,not working

Answer (score -1):

There are two things you should try:

1. Wordpress loads jQuery in compatibility mode, so you will need to use the noconflict syntax, ex. `jQuery('.text-white.follow').plate();`. More information:

   - https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/
   - https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/
2. If you are using a child theme, you need to call `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()`. Parent theme assets are accessed using `template`, and child theme assets are accessed using `stylesheet`.